# Does anyone know of a FAX adapter for BizTalk Server 2009?

Tags: c#, biztalk

I found one example on CodeProject that was implemented for (I believe) BTS 2006.  It looks like it would work, and if nothing else, it's a reasonable implementation of the BTS Samples base adapter.  I'm just wondering if there are any commercial adapter packs including a FAX adapter, or if anyone else here has run across a need to send facsimile data out of a BTS application, and how they chose to address the problem.

Part of me says I could simply write the fax TIFF and a small XML message to a folder (with address info etc.), then write an external service to do the faxing using the built-in fax system in Win2K3.  That seems like another possible alternative, since it would put the responsibility for confirming availability of the fax hardware, monitoring the queue, fault handling etc. outside the BTS application.

Anyway, I'm open to thoughts and suggestions - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I'm either asking a completely ridiculous question, or there is no turnkey solution out there.  I spent some time researching custom adapters and wrote my own   (adapting a sample adapter that was provided by Microsoft) to work with the Microsoft Fax Service.  It should work fine, since the service provides a queue, reducing contention for the hardware.
Thanks anyway...

Comment: You're right - there isn't an official adapter to supports faxing messages to trading partners. Its either a roll your own adapter, or squirt some data at a custom web-service that invokes the MS Fax API.

Answer (score 0):

One of the primary design goals of BizTalk Server is to facilitate the exchange of business documents between trading partners. To help meet this goal, BizTalk Server includes several adapters that provide connectivity between BizTalk Server and trading partners using commonly recognized data protocols and document formats.
hope this help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15748/Fax-Adapter